# Angular 1.5+ Nested Component binding on the value returned by promise

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently learning AngularJS component. I'd like to bind a value between a parent component and a child component, knowing that the value in the parent component is returned by a RESTful service:

**parent.template.html**

```
<h3>{{$ctrl.hero.name}}</h3>
<child hero="$ctrl.hero"></child>
```

**parent.component.js**

```
 angular.module('myApp')
    .component('parent', {
        templateUrl:'parent/parent.template.html',
        controller: ['MyService','$routeParams', parentController]
    });

function parentController(MyService, $routeParams) {
    var self = this;
    MyService.get({ heroId: $routeParams.heroId })
        .$promise
            .then(function (data) {
                self.hero = data; 
                console.log("self.hero:" + self.hero); //this will log the hero correctly.
            });
    console.log("self.hero.name"+ self.hero.name) // this will log "undefined"
};
```

**child.template.html**

```
<div>{{$ctrl.hero.name}}</div>
```

**child.component.js**

```
    angular.module('myApp')
    .component('child', {
        templateUrl:'child/child.template.html',
        controller: childController,
        bingdings: {
            hero:'='
        },
        transclude:true
    });

function childController() {
    var self = this;
    console.log("child hero: " + self.hero); // this will output "undefined"
};
```

I suppose that the child component couldn't get the "hero" from the parent component due to the fact that the "hero" is returned by the $promise.

Do you have ideas how to binding the value like this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Regards,
Leona

Comment: @raina77ow I would give you the right answer !....
This is due to the mis-spell of "bindings" ...
Thanks...

Comment: For user who will look at this post in the future:
We could bind the value returned by $promise as usual. if you can't, double check the spelling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it's a simple typo - should be `bindings` instead of `bingdings`. As a sidenote, in this particular case it's beneficial to use so-called [one-way binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-), available since version 1.5:

```
.component('child', {
  templateUrl:'child/child.template.html',
  controller: childController,
  bindings: {
    hero: '<'
  },
  transclude:true
});
```

... as changes in child component should never affect parent scope here, and they won't be tracked. That's good - both memory and speed-wise.